# Lost iceauthority afer password change

Tags: password-recovery

I changed my password then chnaged it back again.
Now I cant get back into my user adnin
message...could not update ICEauthority file/home/username/.ICEauthority
This has probably been covered can somone point

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that file has wrong permissions or belongs to another user. Check that it belongs to your user and has only read and write permissions to that user:

```
sudo -i
ls -la /home/<your_username>/.ICEauthority
(example output) -rw------- 1 username username 109968 Sep 10 10:30 /home/username/.ICEauthority
```

If something is wrong you can fix it with those commands, then logout and login again:

> To fix the ownership: `sudo chown <your_username>:<your_username> /home/<your_username>/.ICEauthority`
>
> To fix read/write permissions: `sudo chmod 600 /home/<your_username>/.ICEauthority`

Hope this helps.

Comment: to salem HI   on ls -la ~/.ICEauthority I get ls cannot acess /home/username/.ICEauthority: no such file or directory

Comment: if I write  sudo chmod 600 ~/.ICEauthority it asks for password then says cannot acess no such file or directory

Comment: to salem HI on ls -la ~/.ICEauthority I get ls cannot acess /home/username/.ICEauthority: no such file or directory

Comment: yes you are right, i think if using sudo ~ is interpreted as the root's home folder. I updated the answer.

Comment: ls -la /home/<your_username>/.ICEauthority  bash: antony: No such file or directory   maybe I wrote it wrong?

Comment: you replaced <your_username> with your real username? If that file don't exist just create it: `touch ~/.ICEauthority`

Comment: -bash: /root/.ICEauthority  = No sduch file or directory

Comment: you there?  ~/.ICEauthority     =-bash: /root/.ICEauthority = No such file or directory

Comment: I wrote sudo -i       
ls -la /home/antony/.ICEauthority  it gives me No such file or directory does this mean ice is missing?

Comment: i think it should be create automatically. Create using the `touch` command, but with your current user, not root. You can do it pressing ALt+F2 and inserting it there.

Comment: can you run me through the touch command I am not familiar thanks...do I just write touch first?

Comment: i wrote                   touch/.ICEauthority   iT gave me no such file did I write it wrong?

Comment: its late here where I am maybe you can have a think send me some info when you have time thanks..maybe I need to remove the old ICE file or something first

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this.
The problem was with 11.10 in some way.
I had given up, so I put the 12.04 CD in to start the new installation.
Well I thought that I would just try the proceedure 1 more time.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media$ sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
INFO: Found [/mnt/home/.ecryptfs/antony/.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: y
```

Well with the 12.04 live CD it all went correctly and offered me the chance to use my mount passphrase at last.
And I just copied the home directory into my w7 partition while I re-installed.
So the lesson is use the 12.04 live cd even if you are running 11.10 etc.
Alls well that ends well.